# How to get the first row of a result in Yii2? (queryRow Equivalent)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

how can i get the first row of result? Below is my code which is giving me an error like this `Undefined index: module`

```
if ( substr( $action, 0, 4 ) === "stl_" )
            {
                $query  = "SELECT * FROM a_actions LEFT JOIN a_modules ON ( a_modules.id=a_actions.module_id )
                        WHERE a_actions.id=(SELECT dependency FROM a_actions WHERE action='{$action}') AND a_modules.module_status = 1 ";
                $action = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $query )
                                        ->queryAll();
//print_r($action);die();
                $module = $action[ 'module' ];
                $action = $action[ 'action' ];
            }
```

$action has value

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [module_id] => 7 [action] => index [label] => Members [dependency] => [created_by] => [created_at] => [updated_by] => [updated_at] => [is_deleted] => 0 [module] => members [module_name] => [module_status] => 1 ) )
```

in Yii1 i would have used

```
$action = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $query )
                                        ->queryRow();
```

Comment: In Yii2 you can use `queryOne()`: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryOne%28%29-detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `queryOne()`

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $query )
->queryOne();
```

[QueryOne()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryOne%28%29-detail)